# Как составить sql запрос типа HAS_MANY и HAS_ONE

Tags: php, sql, join

Покажите пример составления запроса со связями на  sql, знаю как это реализовать средствами фреймворка, а с sql не получается. Предполагаю что нужно использовать join и группировку , но на практике не могу это сделать.

Comment: ну со связью просто join и в `on` задаем условия связи. А группировки под конкретные случаи пишутся. они к типу связи таблиц вообще отношения не имеют

Answer (score 1):

Таблица 1 (id,value)  [1,1; 2,2;]
Таблица 2 (id,value2) [2,3; 3,4;]
inner join выбираются ключи которые присутствую в связанных таблицах

`select id,value,value2`
`from Таблица 1 t1`
`inner join Таблица 2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id`

в нашем случае данный запрос вернет  1 запись

2,2,3

left join 
выбирает все записи из левой части

`select id,value,value2`
`from Таблица 1 t1`
`left join Таблица 2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id`

вернет

1,1,null

2,2,3

аналогично работает right
только выбирается из правой части

2,2,3

3,null,4